# Multiple filter option in Django Admin Charfield

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

How to filter  multiple option in a admin.py,

Models.py

```
banana_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_("Banana Name"))
```

Admin.py

```
list_filter = [
        "banana_name",
        ]
```

in banana_name there are multiple banana name , right now i can select one banana name at a time or all or none at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one: [django-more-admin-filters](https://github.com/thomst/django-more-admin-filters)